# Replacing Rows or Columns using Indexing (or efficient too solutions) instead of "Cat "

Tags: matlab, indexing, accelerometer, cat

With Arduino, NeoGPS and an MPU6050 i log some data on a SD Card.

On Matlab i am trasforming the accelarations from  MPU6050 from the byte values to m/s^2.

1. The code loads the data on Matlab
2. It extracts **ax ay az**
3. Call a funcion that convert from byte to m/s^2
4. It define the all the columns to be concatenated
5. It concatenates the all the columns

I have a civil engineer back ground, so i am not very practical with coding.

**I was wondering if exists a more efficient solution in particular using Indexing?**

Here my **dumb** code

```
%Open the file 
filename= uigetfile ('.csv');
fileID = fopen (filename);
logmpu6050 =csvread(filename);
fclose (fileID); 

%Converting acceleration from Byte to m/s^2
[ax,ay,az]=convms(logmpu6050);


%Replacing the old accelaration values with the new 
cat1=logmpu6050(:,1:8);
cat2=cat(2,ax,ay,az);
cat3=logmpu6050(:,13:15);
newlogmpu6050= cat(2,cat1,cat2,cat3);
```

**Always thanks for your patience!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the concatenation of `ax, ay, az` in the middle, it breaks the flow that you would use for indexing into `logmpu6050` so you can't use indexing entirely to create the matrix.

However if you want to do it in a single line, you could do something like:

```
newlogmpu6050 = [logmpu6050(:,1:8) ax ay az logmpu6050(:,13:15)];
```

This still performs the desired concatenation, but you're not unnecessarily calling `cat` and to me this looks a lot neater.